# Unable to call JSInterop from new circuit in Blazor Server app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I'm unable to call a JSInterop method after opening a new circuit. I'm creating the new circuit by opening a new tab from JS like this:
`await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "/new-tab", "_blank");`

Next, in my component that is rendered in the new tab I'm attempting to call a JS method like this:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    if (firstRender)
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myJSmethod");
}
```

As soon as the jsRuntime call is made, I receive the following error:

```
The connection to ws://localhost:53216/myapp/ was interrupted while the page was loading.
dotnet-watch reload socket error.
> error { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, srcElement: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, 
composed: false, ... }
dotnet-watch reload socket closed.
```

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please tell me what the `myJSmethod` do? If you don't call it, the new tab will work well or not?

Comment: @BrandoZhang myJSmethod is going to have an onclick event handler for a <ul> list on the page, but for now it just has a "console.log" statement so I can see when it gets called.

Comment: have you tried triggering the method "onload"?  (seems like you're sending a request while the page is still loading?)

Comment: @tjxx I think you need to post more code so it's easier to understand what is going on.  Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: @JasonD Tbh I'm not sure if there is any other code that is relevant, but I'll try to add something helpful.

Comment: @pcalkins I have not tried that yet. How might I do that?

Comment: Ideally if you could provide a minimally reproducible example that would be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example